# R How to write factors as strings to csv

Tags: r

I have an spss labelled heaven dataframe.

```
library(haven)
x <- labelled(sample(5, 10, replace = TRUE), c(Bad = 1, Good = 5))
```

When I use write.csv2(...) all my factors inside of the dataframe are only saved numeric.

```
write.csv(x, row.names = F)
"x"
2
2
4
4
4
2
5
5
5
5
```

But I want to have the strings.

If I use `as.character`.. it returns only the numbers as characters.

There is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438926/export-data-frame-as-factors) which says that the normal behavior of write.csv is to save the factors as strings... but not in my case.

In my case my factors have the class: "haven_labelled" "vctrs_vctr"     "double"

What can I do to save it correctly as strings?

Comment: Try `as.character()` over your variables, then save the file!

Comment: @G.Grothendieck i edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `dput(x)` we see that we have neither a data frame nor factors but we can convert it.

```
library(haven)
library(tibble)

write.csv(as_factor(as_tibble(x)), stdout(), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
value
4
Good
3
2
4
Good
3
Bad
2
Good
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
when you use as_factor(x) .. it will do exactly what i wanted.
But be careful... dont use as.factor(x)