# File format that holds information about categorical data (i.e. factor levels) and is readable by SPSS

Tags: r, spss, categorical-data

I'm doing data cleaning of survey data in R, but at the end I have to export it into a format that is readable by SPSS. When I export data from R as CSV, categorical data with already defined factor levels is treated as simple text and therefore I have to tell SPSS to transform it to categorical data again – which is annoying. Is there a way to keep data type information in a data file? Which file format is suitable?

Comment: Maybe use the `haven` package to export to .sav directly. You can also use `rio::export` that provides a simpler wrapper for common export functions to many formats and uses `haven` for SPSS formats.

Comment: this may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438926/export-data-frame-as-factors